# How to draw Pixel Perfectly on iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: opengl-es, core-animation, pixel, iphone-6-plus, metal

Given the iPhone 6 Plus is downscaling from 1242x2208 to 1080x1920, and UIKit is doing that, are there other ways of drawing to the screen that permit absolute (pixel perfect) drawing without downscaling?

I imagine, but am not sure, that OpenGL and Metal can draw pixel perfect graphics on iPhone 6 Plus, but don't know how. And am a little confused as to what Core Animation's coordinate systems mean, as I've read elsewhere that it might be able to do pixel perfect drawing, regardless of the Point system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For UIKit the non-integral scale factor doesn't usually matter. For OpenGL or Metal, use the new [`UIScreen nativeScale`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/nativeScale) property to optimally determine the size of your framebuffer or drawable.

Comment: Can something like this also be done for CALayers? I've grown fond of these things.